# Proving a scaling property of the Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

A textbook I've been given states: Let λ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}^d$ and let L = L$_d$ denote the σ-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets. If A ∈L, then for any c > 0 we have cA∈L and λ(cA) = c$^d$λ(A). Here cA := {ca : a ∈A} with λ being the Lebesgue measure. This theorem's proof however has been left as an exercise and I was wondering how I could go about doing so:

Here are my general ideas: for cA∈L; A∈L means for every E ⊆ $\Bbb{R}^d$ λ(E ∩ A) + λ(E \ A) = λE hence it would suffice to show λ(E ∩ cA) + λ(E \ cA) = λE however I'm unsure about how I could possibly do this, however λ(cA) = c$^d$λ(A) seems pretty simple as λ(cA) = $\prod_{n=1}^d$cλ(A$_n$) = c$^d$$\prod_{n=1}^d$λ(A$_n$)=c$^d$λ(A) however such a proof would need to be rigorous. How do I go about proving this in a rigorous manner?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @AnotherUser Thank you, I'm new here, changes should be done now